# Highlighting the second and more duplicate rows in excel but not first occurrence?

Tags: excel

I have 25,000 rows in my excel. I want to highlight duplicate rows by taking the data of the columns.

```
Name    Age Sal
abc     12  1200
**abc   12  1200**
abc     12  1300
**abc   12  1200**
bcd     14  1500
bcd     13  1500
**bcd   14  1500**
```

Here The combination (abc, 12, 1200) came for 3 times. I want to highlight the second and third occurrences but not the first one. similarly the combination (bcd,14,1500) came for 2 times. in this case i want to highlight the second occurrence but not the first one.

Help me out.

Thanks,
Swathi.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula upon making a new rule for the conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1,$B1,$C$1:$C1,$C1)>1
```